# English grammar checkers for gedit or LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, gedit

Please let me know if there are any efficient English grammar checkers available for gedit or LibreOffice on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[LanguageTool](http://www.languagetool.org/)**: An Open Source style and grammar checker for English, French, German, Polish, Dutch, Romanian, and other languages. You can think of LanguageTool as a software to detect errors that a simple spell checker cannot detect, e.g. mixing up there/their, no/now etc. It can also detect some grammar mistakes. It does not include spell checking.

LanguageTool will only find errors for which a rule is defined in its XML configuration files. Rules for more complicated errors can be written in Java.

LanguageTool requires an external link to Java 5.0 or later. The current version only works with OpenOffice.org 3.0.1 or later and LibreOffice and you need to restart OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice after installation of this extension.

**Installation and Usage**

In OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice: Double click LanguageTool-1.3.1.oxt to install it. If that doesn't work, call Tools -> Extension Manager -> Add... to install it. Close OpenOffice.org and re-start it. Type some text with an error (e.g. "This is an test." – make sure the text language is set to English) and you should see a blue underline.

Also see [Usage](http://www.languagetool.org/usage/) for using LanguageTool outside of OpenOffice.org.

Comment: Thought it might be nice to have instructions on how to install Sun Java 6, as located here... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Installation%20of%20Java%20Runtime%20Environment%20and%20its%20browser%20plugin

Answer (score 1):

The LibreOffice grammar checker [Lightproof](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice-lightproof-en/) is already packaged in the repositories, and is easy to install. Install the package `libreoffice-lightproof-en` (or `-hu` for Hungarian or `-ru-ru` for Russian), and restart Libreoffice if it’s running.

Note that [the available grammar checks](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/lightproof/tree/src/en/en.dat) are more limited than in MS Office, so if it seems to not be working, that might be the reason. Try “and and”, which should get a wavy blue underline if it’s working.